# How can I pass Strings across Methods?

Tags: java, methods

I am extremely new to Java, and I am having an error that I do not know how to solve. It seems I can't pass the String maincmd: `String maincmd = "op" + "\t" + sender.getName();` into a new method called dispatcher. I also can't use the dispatcher functionality and in the same method, onCommand.

I am overriding methods in a Minecraft related Abstract Class.

```
package bukkit.simondoestuff;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.command.ConsoleCommandSender;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class OpCodesMain extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().info("OPME Successful Startup");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable(){
        getLogger().info("OPME Successful Shutdown");
    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        String maincmd = "op" + "\t" + sender.getName();
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("opme")) {
            if (sender.hasPermission("opme.bypass")) {
                dispatcher(maincmd);
            } else {
                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    sender.sendMessage("§7/opme [key]");
                } else {
                    if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("31415926")) {
                        dispatcher(maincmd);
                        sender.sendMessage("§7OPME: §aCorrect Code Received");
                    } else {
                        sender.sendMessage("§7OPME:" + "§cIncorrect Code Received");
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        return false;

    } // onCommand close

    public void dispatcher(String maincmd, ConsoleCommandSender console) {
        Bukkit.dispatchCommand(console, maincmd);
    }
} // end class
```

Comment: "...dispatcher functionality and in the same method, onCommand."

Meant "...dispatcher functionality in the same method, onCommand."

Comment: Feel free to [edit] your question if you want to correct something

Comment: Your `dispatcher` method requires two parameters but you only give 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your method requires a [`ConsoleCommandSender`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/command/ConsoleCommandSender.html) parameter, which is a sub-interface of [`CommandSender`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/command/CommandSender.html), in addition to `maincmd`. So the  only thing you  are doing wrong is ignoring this parameter. That being said, the only possible instance you can pass is `sender`, which requires some risky casting. I would suggest changing your code to avoid such casting, but here is a dirty solution that fits your current version:

```
dispatcher(maincmd, (ConsoleCommandSender) sender);
```